# Why doesn't my dishwasher spray consistently?

Tags: dishwasher

I have a frigidaire dw that is not spraying. I've engaged the switch to watch it spray for 1-2 seconds, then the water just drains through the top rack sprayer. I found a broken impeller on the circulation pump and replaced the pump. The continuity on the inlet valve is good and not clogged. I noticed that the float never engages. Possibly it is not filling with enough water to begin with...

I've removed everything under the bottom rack to look for debris, etc. All is clear

I'm stumped

Joe

Comment: Some racks spray from a connection in the back of the dishwasher some spray from the bottom center , low water would affect the spray as would a plug caused from a piece of the impeller lodged in the supply pipe as they are parallel paths for the bottom and middle a little information would be helpful.